# What's wrong with this class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason, one of my Ruby on Rails classes produces this sort of error everytime I try to call any method on it:

```
undefined method `create' for Thread:Class
```

I created this class just like any other, using `./script/generate model Thread`, and then migrating it. So why is it acting so strange?

Comment: Perhaps, could you post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a Thread class in ruby maybe its a name clash